# How to receive MSB ans LSB values to convert on integer python

Tags: python

I have a problem with my code.

I need to receive a MSB and LSB 10 bits data from a PICAXE KIT, but i dont know how i can convert the MSB ans LSB on integer that can i use.

I try that, but dont works

```
    for x in range(1,400,10):
    MSB = ser.read(2)
    LSB = ser.read(2)




    datos = (MSB*256)+LSB
    print datos
    degree = float(int(datos,2))


    linea = (432,200)     
    linea_len = 100 
    x = linea[0] + math.cos(math.radians(degree)) * linea_len 
    y = linea[1] + math.sin(math.radians(degree)) * linea_len
```

How can i receive the MSB and LSB from picaxe by serial??

Thanks you

Comment: Take a look at the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#module-struct) module.

Comment: How are you sending them from the PICAXE?